# Why, request return symbol — '?'

Tags: laravel

Why any value in a variable `$search` return a character — `?`?

```
$search = 'words'
Post::where("description", 'like', "%".$search."%")->toSql();
```

Result:

```
"select * from `post` where `description` like ?"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `toSql()` does not include bindings, and therefore you're seeing the question mark in their place.  To see the bindings, you can use getBindings() like so:

```
$search = 'words';
Post::where("description", 'like', "%".$search."%")->getBindings();
```